# Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'summary': object 'X' not found

Tags: r, logistic-regression, weighted

I tried running a weighted stepwise logistic regression using the following R-code:

```
summary(stepAIC(Test_model_2, # the model containing no variables
            direction = 'forward', 
            scope = list(upper = Test_model_1, 
                      # the model with all variables
                         lower = Test_model_2), 
                      # the model with no variables
            trace = 0))
```

When I run models individually using the `summary(Test_model_1)` command, they work fine but when I try to perform the stepwise regression using the above command I get the following error.

```r
Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) : 
error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'summary': object 'vote' not found
```

For more info, I built my models using the following commands:

```
Test_model_1 <- svyglm(vote ~ (agea + stfeco + gndr + lrscale), 
                       family=quasibinomial, design = Test)
Test_model_2 <- svyglm(vote ~ agea, family=quasibinomial, design = Test)
```

Any ideas why I am getting this errors?

I couldn't run the stepwise command without errors.

Comment: You appear to be using several packages for which there are no `library` calls in the code you offered. You also have no code to set up the calls to `svyglm`. Requests for debugging help require full code.

Comment: You should add both comments to the code block in your question. Such details do not belong in comments per longstanding SO policy, because comments do not support proper code format.